# Flutter ListView con espacio al final

Tags: ios, flutter, android-listview

Tengo un ListView que es un StatefulWidget, que utilizo en varias partes de mi app, sin embargo en algunas partes se muestra con un espacio al final.
Este espacio igual se repite en algunas ListView que tengo en la app, y solo en iOS.

Este es un ejemplo lo mas reducido posible. como vemos el container rojo tiene al listview, mientras cada objeto del listview tiene Amber.

```
class RegistrarCliente extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool isGimFinal, liteVersion;
  final String gim, suc;

  const RegistrarCliente(
      {this.isGimFinal, this.liteVersion, this.gim, this.suc});

  @override
  _RegistrarClienteState createState() => _RegistrarClienteState();
}

class _RegistrarClienteState extends State<RegistrarCliente> {
  List<String> list;

  _cargaListBase() {
    list = [
      AppLocatizations.of(context).getTranslation('nombres'),
      AppLocatizations.of(context).getTranslation('nombres')
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _cargaListBase();
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            primary: false,
            itemCount: list.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Center(
                  child: Container(
                      color: Colors.amber, child: Text(index.toString())));
            }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: podrías agregar el código que usas?

Comment: listo, le he buscado y buscado, y solo esta presente en iOS

Comment: pues no se ve nada raro ahí, a lo mejor en el widget padre tienes algo más? ese donde incluye el appbar y demás

Comment: Exacto no hay nada raro, pero en Android ni web, se ve ese espacio… es lo que me intriga más.

Comment: los ListView vienen por default con un padding, puedes ponerlo a zero también.

Comment: Eso fue!, agregue padding a 0; no considere que lo tuviera.

Comment: genial, ahí puse mi respuesta, para que quede registrada y otros se beneficien :) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `ListView` y algunos otros widgets traen un `padding` por defecto.

Puedes asignarle cero para evitar el padding por default:

```
padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
```